# What method or command that run before loading the view from nib file?

Tags: ios, xcode

When create the new objective-c class UIViewController file.
I want to know which command/ method/ line in ViewController.m file or from other file is execute before it generate the view from nib file.

I only know that viewDidLoad will run first before the nib file.
Is there any thing else?

Thank for helping little noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method that is called before your view hierarchy is loaded is the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.
Then the first time you access the view controller's `view` the `nib` is loaded (via the `loadview` method) and then the `viewDidLoad` method is called.
I hope that this makes it clear.

Ps. Although you could override `loadview` method, Apple states that:

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the
>   view controller, you must not override this method. (*Apple's documentation on loadview method*)

Comment: That's very clear. Thank a lot. A little thing. If I call `[ViewController alloc]` or `[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]` and I call `[self viewDidLoad]` again. Am I gonna get the same as when the view is generate when run it?

Comment: You do not call viewDidLoad on self. This is a delegate method that gets called for you when the view hierarchy has been loaded (from the nib in your case). Also what's the point of initializing your controller without passing a nib, if this is the source of your views? As a general rule: You override `loadview` method only when you intent to create your view hierarchy programmatically and not via a nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-(void)loadView` method. It's called before the view controller's view is set and actually this is the place, where you want to set the `view` property of the `self` (the controller).

```
-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...]; //Or get it from the nib...
}
```